# Complex numbers high powers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

The question is:

[image]

I was wondering if somebody could give me sope tips or some topics to learn and some hints as well to be able to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $e^{i\theta}=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$

Comment: Have you tried using Euler's formula? $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$?

Comment: @DonThousand Yes, that's the only step I did. I don't understand how can I compute argument of z, with ((e^i*(pi/5))^15)/(-2+2i)^20

Comment: Use the same formula to write the denominator as $(re^{i\theta})^{20}$.

Comment: $\left(e^{i\pi/5}\right)^{15}=e^{i3\pi}=-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If you write a complex number in the form $re^{i\theta}$ where $r>0$ and $\theta$ are real, then you can take advantage of the fact that $$(re^{i\theta})^n =r^n e^{in\theta}$$
Then you can use the fact that $$\frac{r_1e^{it_1}}{r_2e^{it_2}} = \left(\frac{r_1}{r_2}\right)e^{i(t_1-t_2)}$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I found Arg(z) = [1/sqrt(8)] * e^8pi and |z| = 1 - sqrt(8).

Comment: I think neither of those is correct, you should re-examine them

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{(a) }\text{Arg}(z) = 15 \text{Arg}(\cos \pi/5 +i\sin \pi/5) - 20 \text{Arg}(-2 + 2i).$$

$$\text{(b) }\text{The magnitude of the numerator is }1.$$